# error while improving Chromedriver undetectability

Tags: selenium, perl, selenium-chromedriver

Using C#, I have
`driver = new ChromeDriver();`

It gives:

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.`

It worked before I changed something.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108199/14616587) answer specifies that to improve undetectability of Selenium, you have to run a certain PERL script. I ran it like so:

`perl -pi -e 's/cdc_/dog_/g' C:\Users\user\source\repos\SleeveAce\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.91.0.4472.10100\driver\win32\chromedriver.exe`

What do I do now? Before, the C# app was working perfectly, now it has that error. When I open the .exe as a notepad++ and search for `cdc_`, I find multiple instances, so I suppose the script is not working? I might be wrong though if the script was not supposed to do that.

***EDIT: I have just tried changing all the `cdc_` values in a hex editor as well with `dog_`. They were modified successfully. However, the error is still there.***

***EDIT2: Solved! See comments for explanation.***

**Additional info**

- Using Perl 5 v32
- After running the script, nothing was shown (no
  errors too!)

Comment: what is version of chrome and chrome driver are you using.

Comment: ```Selenium WebDriver 3.141.0```, ```Chrome WebDriver 91.0.4472.10100```

Comment: Google Chrome Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled Chrome WebDriver, did NOT run the Perl script, instead ran hex editor and everything works now. Devs, don't make the same mistake as me of running that script; I have no idea what's wrong with it and have no time to check, but it didn't work. Find+Replace in Hex Editor instead!

Comment: If this is a Windows build of Perl, the command will turn 0A into 0D 0A, breaking the binary. Add `BEGIN { binmode STDOUT }`, and you might have to avoid `-i`.

Comment: If this is a Windows build of Perl, the input and output would need to be `binmode` to prevent CRLF<->LF conversions.