# I want to edit a file with perl, but it doesn't find my file

Tags: perl

I want to edit a file; it's the chromedriver.exe. The problem is that when I write this command:

```
perl -pi -e 's/cdc_/dog_/g' /path/to/chromedriver
```

It replies: "No such file or directory."

Where must I place my file, or how can I edit it?

Comment: You're on Windows. You need to use a Windows path, eg. `C:\path\to\chromedriver`. Second, `/path/to/chromedriver` is an example. You need to replace it with the real path to `chromedriver` on your system. Third, on Windows, you'll probably need to add an `.exe` extension to the filename.

Comment: Since this is windows you need double quotes around your code after the '-e'.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that you would be able to successfully in-place edit a Windows executable with a Perl one-liner. If anything, you would probably just corrupt the file and make it unusable.

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned that you want to edit `chromedriver.exe`, but your command was:

```sh
perl -pi -e "s/cdc_/dog_/g" /path/to/chromedriver
```

Instead, use:

```sh
perl -pi -e "s/cdc_/dog_/g" /path/to/chromedriver.exe
# see the difference starting here --------------^
```

... to match the actual filename. Be sure to back up the original file if it's not easily recoverable!

As a side note, I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68146540/4957508) from Jun 26, 2021 that pointed to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146540/error-while-improving-chromedriver-undetectability#comment120442807_68146540):

> Ok, I reinstalled Chrome WebDriver, did NOT run the Perl script, instead ran hex editor and everything works now. Devs, don't make the same mistake as me of running that script; I have no idea what's wrong with it and have no time to check, but it didn't work. Find+Replace in Hex Editor instead!

As a second side note, [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2230042/kyle) made a comment that [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770608/selenium-does-not-work-with-a-chromedriver-modified-to-avoid-detection#comment118944981_52090113) an important point:

> Keep the $ mark and don't change the length of the key, and you'll be fine

I noticed that your perl script doesn't require a leading `$`, so without being sure what you're trying to replace, I might suggest:

```sh
perl -pi -e "s/\$cdc_/\$dog_/g" /path/to/chromedriver.exe
```

---

[ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) pointed out that editing a binary file may corrupt it by adding carriage returns to each line. They suggest adding `binmode` to the input and output streams:

```sh
perl -pi -e "BEGIN { binmode STDIN; binmode STDOUT } s/\$cdc_/\$dog_/g" /path/to/chromedriver.exe
```

Comment: Re "*I have no idea what's wrong with it*", This will turn 0A into 0D 0A, breaking the binary. Add `BEGIN { binmode STDOUT }`, and you might have to avoid `-i`.

Comment: Interesting; thanks, @ikegami! I assumed, after finding the second link, that it was corrupting other `cdc_` sections that weren't `$cdc_`. I'll make the update you suggested.

Comment: in my case, it still doesn't work, I always get an error message telling me that the file is corrupt.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, @User58! I've linked a few posts with lots of discussion around it, as well as ikegami's recent comment. Hopefully you'll find a solution to the corruption.

Comment: oh, right, it's not enough. You would need to binmode the input too

Comment: @ikegami please feel free to edit the post to make improvements; I'm not in a place right now where I can experiment with it. Thank you!